# raphael drag and drop object from one container to another container

Tags: html, svg, raphael

I have been able to drag and drop element within same paper. Now I need to be able to drag and drop raphael element from one paper container to another.
Here is the example:

drag  from first svg to second svg

first svg element in html

```html
<svg style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="500" height="260">
  <rect style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" x="10" y="15" width="64" height="64" r="5" rx="5" ry="5" fill="#ffc0cb" stroke="#000">
  </rect>
</svg>
```

second svg element in html

```html
<svg style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" </svg>
```

First of all, is it possible to do? If possible, please give me some clue how to do it. thanks!

Comment: How did you do the dragging before, within the same paper?

Comment: just use raphaeljs drag handler.

Answer (score 0):

couple of days later i provided a 'drag drop' functionality to a user, with simple javascript and svg. in which i gave a function which determine exact position of mouse pointer regardless of panning or zooming. have a look at it and see if its useful for you or not. (i don't know how it works in rapheal)

```
 var mainsvg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
function mouseup(event) {
    var svgXY = getSvgCordinates(event);// get current x,y w.r.t to your   svg.
}
    function getSvgCordinates(event) {
                var m = mainsvg.getScreenCTM();
                var p = mainsvg.createSVGPoint();
                var x, y;

                x = event.pageX;
                y = event.pageY;

                p.x = x;
                p.y = y;
                p = p.matrixTransform(m.inverse());

                x = p.x;
                y = p.y;

                x = parseFloat(x.toFixed(3));
                y = parseFloat(y.toFixed(3));

                return {x: x, y: y};
            }
```